# mover objeto jlabel con hilo

Tags: java

Tengo este código, la idea es que a traves de la interfaz Runnable, se crea un hilo que llama a un método "mover", el método mueve un objeto JLabel. El programa compila y todo pero no mueve el objeto JLabel. He probado volver estático el objeto JLabel, el método, volverlos públicos, pero nada. Podrían ayudarme :)

Clase Hilo

```
 package pruebasgraficas;

 import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;


 public class Hilo implements Runnable
 {


         @Override
     public void run()
     {
                 do
         {
             try
             {
                 sleep (1000);
             }catch (InterruptedException e) 
                 {
                     ;
                 }
             PruebasGraficas pu = new PruebasGraficas();
             pu.mover();


         }while(true);
     }
 }
```

clase PruebasGraficas

```
 package pruebasgraficas;


 import java.awt.Color;
 import javax.swing.*;


 public class PruebasGraficas extends JFrame{

 private JLabel et1;

 private static Hilo h1;

     public PruebasGraficas()
     {
         super("mover");
         setLayout(null);

         et1 = new JLabel( );
         et1.setSize(30,30);
         et1.setLocation(10,10);
         et1.setOpaque(true);
         et1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
         add(et1);

         h1 = new Hilo();

     }

     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         PruebasGraficas o = new PruebasGraficas();
         o.setSize(500,500);
         o.setVisible(true);

         h1.run();

     }

     public void mover()
     {
         et1.setLocation( et1.getX() + 5, et1.getY() );
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

La mayoría de los componentes de swing no son thread-safe. Solo puedes actuar sobre ellos en el [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) para que tomen efecto. En consecuencia si utilizas otro hilo y modificas el componente gráfico no va a hacer nada en ese hilo.

Otro problema que tienes es que estás creando un nuevo JFrame cada 1 segundo.

He modificado tu ejemplo para que funcione, sin embargo te recomiendo que uses un layout que no sea null.

La clase Hilo

```
static class Hilo implements Runnable {
    final PruebasGraficas pu;


    public Hilo(PruebasGraficas pu) {
        this.pu = pu;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //con esto te aseguras que se ejecute en el EDT
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                this.pu.mover();
            });

        } while (true);
    }

}
```

Y luego tu JFrame

```
class PruebasGraficas extends JFrame {

        private JLabel et1;

        private static Hilo h1;

        public PruebasGraficas() {
            super("mover");
            this.setLayout(null);

            this.et1 = new JLabel();
            this.et1.setSize(30, 30);
            this.et1.setLocation(10, 10);
            this.et1.setOpaque(true);
            this.et1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.add(this.et1);


        }



        public void mover() {
            this.et1.setLocation(this.et1.getX() + 5, this.et1.getY());
        }

    }
```

El main

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        PruebasGraficas o = new PruebasGraficas();
        o.setSize(500, 500);
        o.setVisible(true);
        // como mencionó luigi
        new Thread(new Hilo(o)).run();

    }
```

Y luego corriendo,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De todas formas la mejor manera de realizar esto es utilizando un [SwingTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) que es especificamente para estas tareas, cada determinado tiempo ejecutas una instrucción en el EDT

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estás usando hilos en tu código. Lo que usas es una implementación directa de `Runnable`, por ende el código se ejecuta de manera secuencial. Un hilo se maneja mediante la clase `Thread` y su ejecución inicia al llamar el método `start`.

Tu código debería lucir así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PruebasGraficas o = new PruebasGraficas();
    o.setSize(500,500);
    o.setVisible(true);
    //aquí se dispara el hilo
    new Thread(h1).start();
}
```

---

Cabe resaltar que el código del hilo tiene una nueva instancia de `PruebasGraficas`, lo cual podría no ser la mejor manera de resolver el problema que planteas. Además, si vas a usar Swing para el entorno gráfico de tu aplicación, sería mejor iniciar los hilos mediante [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) (el cual usa instancias de `Thread` detrás de las escenas).

Comment: ya he modificado mi código pero aun así no se mueve el jlabel :( podrías ayudarme? como seria entonces la mejor manera de llamar al método "mover" sin utilizar otra instancia de PruebasGraficas?

Comment: Envía una instancia de la clase como parámetro al constructor de tu clase que implementa `Runnable`